# saveastable doesn't overwrite the spark table in jupyter notebook?

Tags: pyspark

i do have table X where null values existing in A column , i need to fill those values by LL value. When i do so , overwrite doesn't happen because spark showing error: cannot create managed table. the associated location ('s3a://g-db-X') already exists. what's the algorithm of creating additional tables to bypass this problem?

i created additional same table X-null and then tried to transform it filling null values, and then overwrote X-null table to X table , but it didn't work out. Associated location exists in X table. Expectation: i can overwrite X table